# Network Error in axios post request react-native

Tags: react-native, axios

This is my method to checking Auth by axios post request

```
CheckAuth() {
    let obj = {
                username: 'axy@gmail.com',
                password: 'zzxxz'
            }
    //oauth_credentials imported 

    let form_data = Object.assign(obj, oauth_credentials)

    axios({
           method: 'post',
           url: routes.oauth_token,
           headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'Accept': 'application/json',
           },
           data: form_data
         })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
   }
```

I want to send post request to get token but when i try, It show a Network error in console which is below

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:306)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:269)
```

Comment: what is the value of routes.oauth_token

Comment: http://server.dev/oauth/token

Comment: did you include the protocol?

Comment: yeah i include the protocol . http

Comment: is it iOS & the protocol http

Comment: No it's android and protocol is http

Comment: I faced the same issue. take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/74360433/17643554

Answer (score 7):

If you are facing this error on Android 9, the solution is to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

> Cleartext is any transmitted or stored information that is not encrypted or meant to be encrypted.

As you are using `http` and not `https`, Android Pie will block your requests because cleartext traffic is not permitted by default in Android Pie.

Comment: What about iOS ?

Comment: i'm facing the similar error. I'm using https in the url but it's not work. 
what will be the impact of adding this option in versions prior to android 9 ?

Comment: @WilliamBridge did you solved this?

Answer (score 4):

Try running emulator with `emulator -avd your_avd_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8`
I mean make sure your emulator has an internet connection.

Comment: make sure your emulator has an internet connection. this was the issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a preflighted request because your `content-type` in header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

preflighted requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.

you must ensure the server can manage the OPTIONS request for it to work. or remove it from your request

Comment: what auth method do you use in server?

Answer (score 0):

```
   async getToken(username, password) {
    //request server for token
    try {
        let credential = {
            username: Constant.CLIENT_ID,
            password: Constant.CLIENT_SECRET
        };
        //QueryString is a package
        let data = QueryString.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
            grant_type: 'password'
        });

        //for ios url should be https and for android http
        const requestURL = 'url';
        const response = await axios.post(requestURL, data, {
            auth: credential,
        });
        console.log(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the adb port. write this command

```
adb reverse tcp:8880 tcp:8880; adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081; adb reverse tcp:8881 tcp:8881
```

Answer (score -1):

you go to my command prompt (CMD) or terminal and then type ipconfig its show me the IP address of my machine