# Way ANDROID DEVICES can't send requests to my server

Tags: android, react-native, server, request, apache2

Hello Developers,
thanks for being helpful on all-time.

I'm working on a project it's working fine on Web Navigator `Chrome`,

but when I build the `Android` App using `react-native`, I found that I can't send requests to my server with any of `Axios` or `fetch`.

`catch` is always send
**`Error : Network Error`**, but it's working fine with other servers here's some Screenshots :

[image: my SERVER]

[image: other SERVER]

I can't figure this out, so I expect some help from u guys.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and below permission is used for accessing [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: yes, I have add this attribute too. but stil does not work

Comment: i can fetch from other servers but not mine.

Comment: Are you using localhost sever for this ? If yes, then try replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2.

Comment: no it's https sub domain, can the problem come from the server ?
but it's working fine on localhost i try it

Comment: Can't really say if the problem is from server. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600004/network-error-when-use-axios-in-react-native) and [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3192) can help you.

Comment: thanks for your help, I try my best to fix it but I didn't, I am sure now the problem comes from the server for security reasons.
each of ''/var/log/apache2/error.log" or ''var/log/apache2/access.log"  does not have any trace about the request that i hv sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem before on Android with React Native.

Here are the steps that I did when debugging it:

1. Try to use Postman to check if your endpoint is working.
2. I was using GraphQL so I tested using fetch and axios to see if it returns the same network error.
3. Test on iOS to see if it works or not.

After I did the above, since I deployed my API app on my own server. I pointed my graphql request to my public IP (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/graphql) and it works. You might need to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic = "true"`  to your `AndroidManifest.xml` to make request to http url.

I finally figured out that it was a problem with my SSL certificate that was installed on my domain. I re-installed it back with proper certificate.pem and intermediate.pem and my problem is fixed.

Comment: may the problem is come from SSL on my case too, but we figure out another solution is to link the website with another domain and then it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator uses a virtual network interface, so localhost or 127.0.0.1 refers to the emulator's own loopback interface, not the loopback interface of the host machine where your backend server is running.

Use `http://10.0.2.2:<PORT>` instead of `http://localhost:<PORT>`