# 'AxiosError: Network Error' react native api not calling

Tags: react-native

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.1.90:8080/our_villa/'

const API_SERVICE = {
    Register: BASE_URL + 'register',
}

export default API_SERVICE;
```

```
import API_SERVICE from "./API_SERVICE";
import { UserPOSTRequest } from "./Request";

async function UserRegister(params: any) {
    let url = API_SERVICE.Register
    const result = await UserPOSTRequest(url, params)
    console.log('result ========>', result);
    
    return result
}

export {Register}
```

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import axios from "axios";

async function formDataHeaders() {
    var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    } else {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            "Authorization": token,
        }
    }
}

export async function UserPOSTRequest(url: any, params: any) {
    let headers = await formDataHeaders();

    try{
        const config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: params,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(params),
        }
        const response = await axios(config)
        return getResponse(response)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return getError(err)
    }
}
```

```
const UserSignUp = async () => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fullname', Name)

    try {
      const response = await UserRegister(formData)      
      console.log('API response true =====>', JSON.stringify(response));
      navigation.navigate('UserSignIn')
    } catch (response) {
      console.log('API response false =====>', response);     
    }

  }
```

`AxiosError: Network Error. how to sol this problem`

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://3.143.212.113/api/'

const API_SERVICE = {
    Register: BASE_URL + 'register',
}

export default API_SERVICE;

// API Request
import API_SERVICE from "./API_SERVICE";
import { UserPOSTRequest } from "./Request";

async function UserRegister(params: any) {
    let url = API_SERVICE.Register
    const result = await UserPOSTRequest(url, params)
    console.log('result ========>', result);
    
    return result
}

export {Register}

// Token request
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import axios from "axios";

async function formDataHeaders() {
    var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    } else {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            "Authorization": token,
        }
    }
}

// method request

export async function UserPOSTRequest(url: any, params: any) {
    let headers = await formDataHeaders();

    try{
        const config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: params,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(params),
        }
        const response = await axios(config)
        return getResponse(response)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return getError(err)
    }
}
```

`// API calling code format`

```
const UserSignUp = async () => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fullname', Name)

    try {
      const response = await UserRegister(formData)      
      console.log('API response true =====>', JSON.stringify(response));
      navigation.navigate('UserSignIn')
    } catch (response) {
      console.log('API response false =====>', response);     
    }

  }
```

Comment: Checkt it please ;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600004/network-error-when-use-axios-in-react-native