# Axios showing Error:" Err_Bad_Request" while sending formdata using React native Expo

Tags: android, react-native, axios, expo

I'm attempting to send both image data (in Buffer format) and some text using `formData` from my Expo React Native application to a Node.js server with MongoDB. Strangely, I'm encountering an issue where my code works perfectly when I use Postman, but it doesn't seem to work as expected in the front end. I'll provide my code below, along with the error I'm facing. The error message indicates that the data is present in the console within the error block, but it doesn't get posted to the database.

Here's my frontend code:

```
export default class Sellnow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangePetName = this.onChangePetName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetTitle = this.onChangePetTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetContact = this.onChangePetContact.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetPrice = this.onChangePetPrice.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetDescription = this.onChangePetDescription.bind(this);
    this.onValueChangeCat = this.onValueChangeCat.bind(this);
    this.onValueChangeCity = this.onValueChangeCity.bind(this);
    this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",

      category: [
        {
          itemName: "Select Category...."
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Food"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Products"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Pets Accessories"
        }
      ],

      cityCategory: [
        {
          itemName: "Select City...."
        },
        {
          itemName: "Islamabad"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Rawalpindi"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Lahore"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Peshawar"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Karachi"
        },
        {
          itemName: "Quetta"
        }
      ]
    };
  }


  onChangePetName(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetTitle(e) {
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetContact(e) {
    this.setState({ contact: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetPrice(e) {
    this.setState({ price: e.target.value });
  }
  onChangePetDescription(e) {
    this.setState({ description: e.target.value });
  }
  // categories function
  onValueChangeCat(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedcat: e.targetvalue })
  }

  // city function
  onValueChangeCity(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedcity: e.targetvalue })
  }

  onFileChange(e) {
    this.setState({ imgforsell: e.targetvalue })
  }

  // uploading Image
  _getPhotoLibrary = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      base64: true,
      exif: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ imgforsell: result });
    }
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      imgforsell: this.state.imgforsell
    });
  };

  async onSubmit() {
    const FormData = global.FormData;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", this.state.name);
    formData.append("title", this.state.title);
    formData.append("contact", this.state.contact);
    formData.append("price", this.state.price);
    formData.append("description", this.state.description);
    formData.append("selectedcat", this.state.selectedcat);
    formData.append("selectedcity", this.state.selectedcity);
    formData.append("imgforsell", this.state.imgforsell)

    axios
      .postForm(
        `http://192.168.88.45:4040/pets/addpets `,
        QueryString.stringify({ formData }),
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
        },
      )
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.toJSON());
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { imgforsell } = this.state
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
> 
> Object {
  "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
  "columnNumber": undefined,
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
    "data": "formData%5B_parts%5D%5B0%5D%5B0%5D=name&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B0%5D%5B1%5D=Dummy&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B1%5D%5B0%5D=title&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B1%5D%5B1%5D=Dummy&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B2%5D%5B0%5D=contact&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B2%5D%5B1%5D=12345678900&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B3%5D%5B0%5D=price&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B3%5D%5B1%5D=1234567&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B4%5D%5B0%5D=description&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B4%5D%5B1%5D=Qwerty%20keypad&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B5%5D%5B0%5D=selectedcat&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B5%5D%5B1%5D=Pets%20Products&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B6%5D%5B0%5D=selectedcity&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B6%5D%5B1%5D=Peshawar&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B0%5D=imgforsell&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bcancelled%5D=false&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bwidth%5D=2160&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BDateTime%5D=2015%3A11%3A04%2017%3A32%3A48&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BSoftware%5D=Adobe%20Photoshop%20CC%20%28Windows%29&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BXResolution%5D=72&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BImageWidth%5D=2160&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BOrientation%5D=0&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BImageLength%5D=1620&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BResolutionUnit%5D=2&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BLightSource%5D=0&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BColorSpace%5D=1&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BJPEGInterchangeFormat%5D=302&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BYResolution%5D=72&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BCompression%5D=6&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bexif%5D%5BJPEGInterchangeFormatLength%5D=5674&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bheight%5D=1620&formData%5B_parts%5D%5B7%5D%5B1%5D%5Bbase64%5D=%2F9j%2F4QG%2BRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAESAAQAAAABAAAAAAEAAAQAAAABAAAIcAEaAAUAAAABAAAAngExAAIAAAAdAAAApgICAAQAAAABAAAWKodpAAQAAAABAAAA3wEDAAMAAAABAAYAAAEbAAUAAAABAAAAwwEBAAQAAAABAAAGVAEyAAIAAAAUAAAAywEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAIBAAQAAAABAAABLgAAAAAACvyAAAAnEEFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAoV2luZG93cykAAAr8gAAAJxAyMDE1OjExOjA0IDE3OjMyOjQ4AAACkggAAwAAAAEAAAAAoAEAAwAAAAEAAQAAAAAAAAAIARoABQAAAAEAAAFjATEAAgAAAB0AAAFrAgIABAAAAAEAABYqAQMAAwAAAAEABgAAARsABQAAAAEAAAGIATIAAgAAABQAAAGQASgAAwAAAAEAAgAAAgEABAAAAAEAAAEuAAAAAAAK%2FIAAACcQQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIChXaW5kb3dzKQAACvyAAAAnEDIwMTU6MTE6MDQgMTc6MzI6NDgAAAEANwADAAAAAQABAAAAAAAA%2F%2BAAEEpGSUYAAQEAAAEAAQAA%2F9sAQwABAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB%2F9sAQwEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB%2F8AAEQgGVAhwAwEiAAIRAQMRAf%2FEAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC%2F%2FEALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29%2Fj5%2Bv%2FEAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC%2F%2FEALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5%2Bjp6vLz9PX29%2Fj5%2Bv%2FaAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A%2FMk%2FearX%2FLP%2FAD%2FeqqfvNTfO%2Fd9f%2FHv9r619Bhf%2FAJA%2FMX0%2FwosUUVYoJK9WKKKD0AqxVepLfv8A9s%2F%2FAGpQBNH97%2FP%2FAE0oP3mqxH97%2FP8A00oP3mrorHnke5fX9DVjcvr%2BhqP7Mv8Ad%2F8AHT%2FjVj7Mv93%2FAMdP%2BNcv1P8Axf1%2F26d913X3r%2FMmooorqOAh3N6%2FoKj8tv8AKD%2FCr37v%2FO6j93%2FndXP9V8vw%2FwDtSub%2B7H7v%2BCVSd3AHr3%2Bvr%2Fun%2FPWaAhOOp%2Fd5PI6Fsdj2%2FwDQucleTyNgwByep2eh9Dnt%2FkmkS38nJPTjA9eXHXORg4PQ5z1IJrfDYdJPq%2Bm%2FRy310t83dvdaNX6dOn3t%2Fj%2Flu7ss1H5Ht%2F45Rb9%2F%2B2f%2FALUqxb9%2F%2B2f%2FALUpiM%2FyPb%2FxyrA%2FcZ%2FzjGf97Ocn86kqPzvf%2FwAe%2FwDr10AWPM9v1%2F8ArUeZ7fr%2FAPWo8v3%2FAE%2F%2BvR5fv%2Bn%2FANegPa%2F3vw%2F4BcooornAjBD5B4PY8%2Bpz29FPX%2BfVqnZuGM9O%2Fp%2BdKVxkjp%2FLnHrk5%2Fz61ZHzgg9V7%2FU%2Bn0%2Bv50q2HTUu6t%2Bc7dev37K7s7NO11una%2Fyba%2FT8bphb9%2F8Atn%2F7UqSiimIKKjm%2Fi%2F4HUlAFfZ%2Fs%2FwDjv%2F1qk8z2%2FX%2F61Sb%2FAPb%2FAPHv%2Fsqk8v3%2FAE%2F%2BvXQHtf734f8AAKdWKr0UAWKsVHb9%2FwDtn%2F7UqSucAooqPzvf%2FwAe%2FwDr0AU9n%2Bz%2FAOO%2F%2FWo2f7P%2FAI7%2FAPWqxv8A9v8A8e%2F%2Byo3%2FAO3%2FAOPf%2FZV0B7X%2B9%2BH%2FAACO37%2F9s%2F8A2pUlFFBzkdv3%2FwC2f%2FtSpKjt%2B%2F8A2z%2F9qVJQdBJ5nt%2Bv%2FwBarHme36%2F%2FAFqr%2BX7%2FAKf%2FAF6seX7%2FAKf%2FAF6A9r%2Fe%2FD%2FgB5nt%2Bv8A9ajzPb9f%2FrVHv%2F2%2F%2FHv%2FALKjf%2Ft%2F%2BPf%2FAGVAe1%2Fvfh%2FwCxRVff8A7f8A49%2F9lUfl%2B%2F6f%2FXrnK%2BsS%2Fn%2F8lX%2FyJYD54A%2FX6%2Bo%2F2T%2FnqAhMgcnueR0Jx29Mf%2FrJpSue%2FwBOP%2Fr0iD5Tjjp83XPJHQnj7pH%2BPUrC4dJN21dr6u2jlvq9vvu3a60Z9Yl37aWXd635e2%2Fysr3I6sVXqTzvf%2Fx7%2FwCvXSSSUUUUAFFFFAFzyPb%2FAMcqOpPO9%2F8Ax7%2F69Hke3%2FjlBzkdWKj8j2%2F8cq5QBTghxu9eO3TlgOM9Tn8PqakqMTeRnvjHP4t29vTPfvu4koOgdsb0%2FUf41Y2N6fqP8aML%2Fe%2F8dP8AjUduF5%2Bb%2Fnn%2FAAn%2FAKae9c%2FsPP8AH%2F7Ur6xL%2Bf8A8lX%2FAMiWqKk8j2%2F8cqv5Ht%2F45QSN2N6fqP8AGjY3p%2Bo%2Fxo3N6%2FoKNzev6Cj2Hn%2BP%2FwBqA2o%2FI9v%2FAByrlR%2BR7f8Ajlc56BX8j2%2F8cqSpPI9v%2FHKuUAV6Kj8j2%2F8AHKkoAKKKKALWxvT9R%2FjRsb0%2FUf40bm9f0FG5vX9BXR7fy%2FD%2FAO2PPAwfK3H%2FAI5%2FtVHH93%2FP96SrB%2B63%2Bf4qI%2Fu%2F5%2FvSVy4vr%2FiX%2FuQ74%2FCvRf8AuQo1J5Ht%2FwCOUeR7f%2BOVcqhlPyPb%2FwAcqSrFFABRUdv3%2FwC2f%2FtSrlABRUfke3%2FjlSUAR%2BR7f%2BOVcoooAj8j2%2F8AHKPI9v8AxyrlFABUfke3%2FjlHke3%2FAI5VygCn5Ht%2F45VyiigAqPyPb%2FxyjyPb%2FwAcq5QBT8j2%2FwDHKPI9v%2FHKuUUAR%2BR7f%2BOUeR7f%2BOVcooAp%2BR7f%2BOUeR7f%2BOVcooAr1YqxRQBXqPyPb%2FwAcq5RQBXoqxRQBXqxRUnke3%2FjlAEdR%2BR7f%2BOVY8j2%2F8cqSgCvViirFAFPyPb%2FxyrHke3%2FjlA%2FfZ%2FznO76Y6H9OTgZseR7f%2BOUAR1H5Ht%2F45VyigAqPyPb%2FAMcqx5Ht%2FwCOVJQBT8j2%2FwDHKuVYqPyPb%2FxygCSo%2FI9v%2FHKseR7f%2BOVJQBH%2FAKN%2FnFHke3%2FjlXKKAI%2FI9v8AxyrHke3%2FAI5VjyPb%2FwAcqSgAqTyPb%2FxyrHke3%2FjlSV54Efke3%2FjlHke3%2FjlXKjH7jP8AnGM%2F72c5P50AUY4Pm6f%2BOf8AXSnVaj%2B9%2Fn%2FppUMEON3rx26csBxnqc%2Fh9TVL4an%2FAG5%2F6UY1vh%2Fr%2BYPI9v8AxypKueZ7fr%2F9arHme36%2F%2FWo5JdvxX%2BZ1fWX%2FAHf%2FAAGX%2FwAkU6j8j2%2F8crQ8z2%2FX%2FwCtUmz%2FAGf%2FAB3%2FAOtRyS7fiv8AMPrL%2Fu%2F%2BAy%2F%2BSKcEON3rx26csBxnqc%2Fh9TR9i%2Fzt%2FwDrVoeR7f8AjlHke3%2FjlSZlfyPb%2FwAcqx5Ht%2F45VzZ%2Fs%2F8Ajv8A9ajZ%2Fs%2F%2BO%2F8A1qrkl2%2FFf5mn1l%2F3f%2FAZf%2FJFPyPb%2FwAco%2Bxf52%2F%2FAFq1Nn%2Bz%2FwCO%2FwD1qsbP9n%2Fx3%2F61HJLt%2BK%2FzD6y%2F7v8A4DL%2FAOSMyCHG7147dOWA4z1Ofw%2Bpo8m19vzNXxD5%2Be3T%2BbD179fw6jGaseR7f%2BOVJ2FDybX2%2FM1P5Ht%2F45Wh5Ht%2F45UlAFPyPb%2FxyrH2L%2FO3%2FwCtR5Ht%2FwCOVqUAZfke3%2FjlAh8%2FPbp%2FNh69%2Bv4dRjNaHke3%2FjlSUAU%2FI9v%2FAByrH2L%2FADt%2F%2BtVjyPb%2FAMcqSgCn5Ht%2F45VypPI9v%2FHKPI9v%2FHKAK%2Fke3%2FjlHke3%2FjlaHke3%2FjlHke3%2FAI5QBB5Nr7fmafV2CHG7147dOWA4z1Ofw%2Bpp9AFTybX2%2FM0eTa%2B35mtCCHG7147dOWA4z1Ofw%2BppPI9v%2FHKAM%2F7Hben%2FAI8KPsdt6f8AjwrQ8j2%2F8cqx5Ht%2F45QBQ8m19vzNHk2vt%2BZq%2FwCR7f8AjlHke3%2FjlAGf5Ht%2F45Vj7F%2Fnb%2F8AWqx5Ht%2F45VjyPb%2FxygCh5Nr7fmaTyPb%2FAMcrZghxu9eO3TlgOM9Tn8PqaTyPb%2FxygDH8j2%2F8cpfJtfb8zWv5Ht%2F45UlAGZ5Nr7fmaTyPb%2FxytDyPb%2FxyjyPb%2FwAcoAz%2FACPb%2FwAco8j2%2FwDHK1Kj8j2%2F8coAoeTa%2B35mk8j2%2FwDHK0PI9v8AxyjyPb%2FxygCh5Nr7fmaTyPb%2FAMcrUooAzPJtfb8zVurnke3%2FAI5QIfIzznGO3u49e2Afox5OaAK%2Fke3%2FAI5R5Ht%2F45VjyPb%2FAMcqx5Ht%2FwCOUAQeTa%2B35mk8j2%2F8crUqS37%2FAPbP%2FwBqUAUIIcbvXjt05YDjPU5%2FD6mk8j2%2F8crUqPyPb%2FxygCDybX2%2FM0eTa%2B35mr4h8jPOcY7e7j17YB%2BjHk5o8j2%2F8coAz%2FI9v%2FHKseR7f%2BOVoeR7f%2BOUeR7f%2BOUAZ%2Fke3%2FjlLBDjd68dunLAcZ6nP4fU1p1H5Ht%2F45QBnyw9cf8A6%2BXzwT%2Fs9O%2BRz8uCeR7f%2BOVoCHz89un82Hr36%2Fh1GM0eR7f%2BOUAUPJtfb8zR5Nr7fma06KAKfke3%2FjlHke3%2FAI5Wh5Ht%2FwCOUeR7f%2BOUAV%2FI9v8AxyjyPb%2FxyrHke3%2FjlHke3%2FjlAFf7F%2Fnb%2FwDWpfJtfb8zWnRQBmeTa%2B35mjybX2%2FM1f8AI9v%2FABypKAMP7Hben%2Fjwo%2Bx23p%2F48K2PsX%2Bdv%2F1qr%2BR7f%2BOUAY%2Fke3%2FjlHke3%2FjlbHke3%2FjlV%2FI9v%2FHKAMfyPb%2FxyjyPb%2FxytjyPb%2Fxyq%2Fke3%2FjlAGf5Ht%2F45S%2BTa%2B35mtOo%2FI9v%2FHKAMjybX2%2FM0nke3%2FjlbHke3%2FjlV%2FI9v%2FHKAMfyPb%2FxyjyPb%2FxytjyPb%2Fxyq%2Fke3%2FjlAGP5Ht%2F45R5Ht%2F45Wx5Ht%2F45VfyPb%2FxygDLqOWHrj%2F8AXy%2BeCf8AZ6d8jn5cHQl%2FcZ7ev6465x07Zzkdc1X8j2%2F8coPPM%2FyPb%2Fxyl8m19vzNX%2FI9v%2FHKr%2BR7f%2BOV6AGf5Ht%2F45R5Ht%2F45WpVOWHrj%2F8AXy%2BeCf8AZ6d8jn5cEAz%2FACPb%2FwAcqv5Ht%2F45WgIfIzznGO3u49e2Afox5OaPI9v%2FABygDH8j732f2zjjPLDuT7E9ewyTuNV%2FI9v%2FABytjyPb%2FwAcqv5Ht%2F45QBQ8m19vzNPrQqPyPb%2FxygCh5Nr7fman8j2%2F8cq5Unke3%2FjlAGfb9%2F8Atn%2F7Uo8j2%2F8AHK0YIcbvXjt05YDjPU5%2FD6mk8j2%2F8coAz%2FI9v%2FHKWCHG7147dOWA4z1Ofw%2Bpq%2F5Ht%2F45RLD1x%2F8Ar5fPBP8As9O%2BRz8uCAZ%2Fke3%2FAI5Udanke3%2FjlHke3%2FjlAGP5Ht%2F45VfyPb%2FxytjyPb%2Fxyib%2BL%2FgdAGf5Ht%2F45R5Ht%2F45VjyPb%2FxyjyPb%2FwAcoAz%2FACPb%2FwAco%2Bxf52%2F%2FAFq1Kj8j2%2F8AHKAM%2FwAj2%2F8AHKPI9v8AxytDyPb%2FAMcqSgDL8j2%2F8cqv5Ht%2F45Wx5Ht%2F45R5Ht%2F45QBl1H9i%2FwA7f%2FrVseR7f%2BOVX8j2%2FwDHKAM%2FyPb%2FAMco8j2%2F8crUqPyPb%2FxygDP8j2%2F8co8j2%2F8AHK0PI9v%2FAByjyPb%2FAMcoAx%2FI9v8AxyrHke3%2FAI5Wh5Ht%2FwCOUeR7f%2BOUAZ8sPXH%2FAOvl88E%2F7PTvkc%2FLgn2L%2FO3%2FAOtWh5Ht%2FwCOUeR7f%2BOUAZ%2Fke3%2FjlAh8jPOcY7e7j17YB%2BjHk5rQ8j2%2F8co8j2%2F8coAp0VqeR7f%2BOUeR7f8AjlAH4%2Bn7zVNBDiNvXjt0%2BdgOM9Tn8PqahP3mrS%2F5Z%2F5%2FvUYX%2FwCQOF9P8KJKKr1Jb9%2F%2B2f8A7UroJLlV6sUUAUdjen6j%2FGrGxvT9R%2FjRub1%2FQVY3N6%2FoKPYef4%2F%2FAGoDaKKK6ANCio7fv%2F2z%2FwDalXK5wK9Sed7%2FAPj3%2FwBeo6sV0HOR%2Bd7%2FAPj3%2FwBepKj8j2%2F8cq5QBGP32f8AOc7vpjof05OBmSirFAFO37%2F9s%2F8A2pVyiigCvRVirFAFeirFV6ALFV6KKACrFV6sUAWKKr0UAWKr0UUAFFFWKAK9FFWKACiiigCxVeirFAFeirFV6ACiiigAooooAKKKkH77P%2Bc53fTHQ%2FpycDIAW%2Ff%2FALZ%2F%2B1KkoooAKKKKACox%2B%2Bz%2FAJznd9MdD%2BnJwMyVYoAj8j2%2F8cqOrFWKAK9FWKj8j2%2F8coAPI9v%2FAByiCHG7147dOWA4z1Ofw%2Bpqx5Ht%2FwCOUQQ43evHbpywHGepz%2BH1NAB5Ht%2F45VypIIcbvXjt05YDjPU5%2FD6mjyPb%2FwAcoAp1J5Ht%2FwCOVoQQ43evHbpywHGepz%2BH1NWPI9v%2FABygDH8j2%2F8AHKPI9v8AxytDyPb%2FAMco8j2%2F8coAjoqPyPb%2FAMcqSgAoqxVegCPyPb%2FxyjyPb%2FxyrlR%2BR7f%2BOUAXKp%2BR7f8AjlXKK5zoM37M393%2FAMdH%2BNH2Zv7v%2Fjo%2FxrQ8tv8AKD%2FCpNzev6Cj2Hn%2BP%2F2oGX9mb%2B7%2FAOOj%2FGpNjen6j%2FGtDc3r%2BgqOZm%2Bbn%2B%2F2FHsPP8f%2FALUBv%2FLP%2FP8AeqrH9...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Here is the screenshot of postman:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Data to Service in Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643330/pass-data-to-service-in-axios)

Comment: @Phil no it doesnot answers my question as I have already tried it before posting my question

Comment: Typically all you need is `axios.post(url, formData)`. That being said, I've seen plenty of reports of issues with react-native `FormData` and Axios. You can try `fetch` as an alternative... `fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: formData })`. Note that at no time have I wrapped `formData` in braces

Comment: @Phil I tried fetch before but it gave me "Network Request error" below this comment I will share my fetch code also

Comment: I think there can be issues with react-native on a device and making unsecured requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49374981/283366

Comment: fetch(
  `http://192.168.10.11" :4000/pets/addpets`,
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }
)
  .then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(res);
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",
    });
  });

Comment: What device are you using, Android or iOS? Why is there a `"` after your IP address in that `fetch` example?

Comment: @Phil I have tried almost every thing from using fetch to changing ip address but nothing works for me

Comment: @Phil I am using android device

Comment: @Phil " this is typo mistake while posting here but not in code

Comment: Can you literally try `fetch("http://192.168.10.11:4000/pets/addpets", { method: "POST", body: formData })`. If that still gives you a _Network Error_, please see the [post I linked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49370747/283366) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46307932/283366)

Comment: It doesn't works

Comment: try to use formdata without `QueryString.stringify`

Comment: @UsamaAltaf already tried

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are sending a image in formData but you have to add `type: 'image/jpeg',` to the file attribute of the formData to fixed this

```
formData.append("imgforsell",this.state.imgforsell)
```

change with this

```
formData.append('imgforsell', {
  uri: "file://" //Your Image File Path
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'imageName'
})
```

Visit [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936988/react-native-axios-trying-to-upload-image) your more doubts will be clear and you will find out how to do it in Ios and Android

Comment: I have tried to change it according to your advise to this but it didnot work    formData.append('imgforsell', {
      uri: "imgforsell",
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'imageName'
    })

Comment: that depends on what is the data in imgforsell it should be file path starts with `file://` use console and check the data

Comment: I am not getting data from any url i am trying to upload from device

Comment: yes but what are you getting in this.state.imgforsell there should be file path after you select the image from device use `console.log()` to see what you are getting after selecting the picture

Comment: Nothing just name of field and in second case un identified

Comment: https://aboutreact.com/file-uploading-in-react-native/

Comment: Just Tried example that you have posted it did not worked with react native expo